# Rake aborting with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Trying to setup the exception_logger plugin on a production server. Everything worked fine on the dev machine. Trying to rake db:migrate on the prod server and i get this error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pagination
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic Pagination is not supported in 2.1 - or at least it is a dead library

http://workingwithrails.com/railsplugin/5289-classic-pagination

Have a look at will_paginate -

http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wikis

that's what all the cool kids are using :-)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the error is related to the pagination plugin. That means the error may not be related to exception_logger at all...

Try `rake db:migrate --trace` and add the additional output to your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pagination
/home/12348/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/nfs/c01/h06/mnt/12348/containers/rails/mpg_prod/vendor/plugins/classic_pagination/init.rb:24:in `evaluate_init_rb'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:95:in `evaluate_init_rb'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:91:in `evaluate_init_rb'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:44:in `load'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:33:in `load_plugins'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:32:in `each'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:32:in `load_plugins'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/initializer.rb:283:in `load_plugins'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/initializer.rb:138:in `process'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/initializer.rb:93:in `send'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/initializer.rb:93:in `run'
/nfs/c01/h06/mnt/12348/containers/rails/mpg_prod/config/environment.rb:13
/home/12348/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/tasks/misc.rake:3
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:546:in `call'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:546:in `execute'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:541:in `each'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:541:in `execute'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:508:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.rb:135:in `synchronize'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:501:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:518:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1183:in `each'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1183:in `send'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1183:in `each'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:515:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:507:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/thread.rb:135:in `synchronize'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:501:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:494:in `invoke'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1931:in `invoke_task'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1909:in `top_level'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1909:in `each'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1909:in `top_level'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1948:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1903:in `top_level'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1881:in `run'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1948:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/lib/rake.rb:1878:in `run'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/gems/rake-0.8.1/bin/rake:31
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/12348/data/rubygems/gems/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your rake is being aborted while loading **environment.rb**.
2. Check for any **missing gems** that are declared in it ton your production machine.
3. "**sudo gem install"** those that are missing
4. Check environment.rb loads up properly by issuing **"script/console"** on your temimal