# Rails 2.3.9, adding ActiveScaffold, getting in `alias_method': undefined method `number_of_pages' for class `Paginator'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have AS (as a plugin) working in another app just fine (I dont remember this
issue...) - its also using Rails 2.3.9, on same dev box.

Now trying to add it to a new app and getting this error when running
the webrick, script/server:

```
/Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/
active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:33:in `alias_method':
undefined method `number_of_pages' for class `Paginator' (NameError)
        from /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/
activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:
33:in `alias_method_chain'
        from /Users/kimptoc/Documents/ruby/borisbikestats/vendor/plugins/
active_scaffold/lib/extensions/paginator_extensions.rb:9
```

I couldn't find any previous references to this error.

Embarassingly I dont know which version of AS I am using successfully... it says 1.2RC1 in the CHANGELOG file, but I seem to remember trying a few of the forks...(is there somewhere I can see which fork is in use...). I have tried using the the 'main' activescaffold in the new project, but it fails as above, but so does using the same plugin that is in the working project :(

Thanks in advance for any pointers as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Chris

PS Just realised that new Rails was using Rails 3 and old/working one was 2.3.9.  It seems you need to use an alternate branch of AS for Rails 3, like this : https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold/wiki

Comment: What version of AS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but built in pagination was removed in Rails 2 as I recall, and you needed to install the classic_pagination plugin to get that functionality back.

I only used ActiveScaffold once, but the error there says `paginator_extensions.rb` ... it's probably monkey patching the old Rails paginator? Therefore the class exists but the number_of_pages method doesn't.

Comment: Thanks - will look into that, although I was using rails 2.3+ and according to this S/O question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188147/rake-aborting-with-error classic_pagination has been dead for a while...

Comment: Hmm, looking at http://rdoc.info/github/activescaffold/active_scaffold/master/Paginator

Comment: ...it would seem like it is supposed to be defined by ActiveScaffold after all, in lib/paginator.rb